# Can't seem to use listview properly

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, listview

My app crashes when trying to use listview.

The xml (called activity_feedbackresults)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>
```

the java

```
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedbackresults);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] arr = {"A","B","C"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_feedbackresults, arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

edit: logcat says ArrayAdapter You must supply a resource ID for a TextView.
I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the constructor that lets you enter textview id and give the id of your textview that you specified int the layout

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_feedbackresults,
            R.id.textviewId,
            arr);
```